# Knockout - looping through an array and keeping track of count?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout object like this,

```
this.results = [ 
    { name: 'aaa', display: true },
    { name: 'bbb', display: false },
    { name: 'ccc', display: true},
    { name: 'ddd', display: true},
    { name: 'eee', display: true}
];
```

I have to populate the data in this table format, with two cells in each row.

The "name" should be displayed only if "display" property is true. Since $index won't work in this case, how can I accomplish this?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ddd</td>
        <td>eee</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll should pair up your results and bind to the paired view of your results.

Without using third party libraries to do this pairing, you'd need to do something like this:

```
this.pairedResults = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var pairedResults = [], currentResult;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.results(), function (result) {
        if (result.display()) {
            if (!currentResult) {
                currentResult = {
                    results: [ result ]
                };
            } else {
                currentResult.results.push(result);
                pairedResults.push(currentResult);
                currentResult = null;
            }
        }
    });
    if (currentResult) {
        pairedResults.push(currentResult);
    }
    return pairedResults;
}, this);
```

Then bind to your view:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: pairedResults">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: results">
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jf7PW/)

Answer (score 0):

Your table doesn't really match up with your model. I'll add name2 to the model for the extra column.

You don't need to refer to index in this case. What you would do is use the if binding on the row.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name1<th>
            <th>Name2</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: results">
        <tr data-bind="if: display">
            <td data-bind="text: name"><td>
            <td data-bind="text: name2"><td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dW7ap/1/

Comment: I have to display two td's in each row. That's what I am not sure how to do.

Comment: Your data didn't have another field for column 2. I've added it as name2.